# How do I handle double quotes in powershell replace?

Tags: xml, powershell, replace

I'm trying to call Powershell from a batch file to replace [task-id type="integer"] in an xml file. Here's what I'm doing:

```
powershell.exe -Command "(gc C:\temp\response.xml) -replace 'task-id type="integer"', 'task-id' | Out-File C:temp\response2.xml"
```

But it doesn't work...

It works fine if I remove the double quotes.

Help!

Comment: What does "...it doesn't work" mean?  Are you getting a powershell error?

Comment: Save this command as an encoded command or save it in a file. Both ways you wont have to worry about escaping. Oh you could go to the trouble of escaping the quotes in batch.